# mysql connector c++ wrapper

Tags: c++, mysql

I found a wrapper code for the mysql connector c++ and now I want to know, how can I use the current connection on every cpp file?

Link to the wrapper: https://github.com/eduardocasas/MySQL-Connector-Cpp-Wrapper-Class

Currently I do queries like this:

```
MySQLConnWrapper conn;
conn.connect();
conn.switchDb("database");
conn.execute("Query");
conn.fetch();
```

but I would like to know, how can I do something like this:
I write on the main function:

```
MySQLConnWrapper conn;
conn.connect();
conn.switchDb("database");
```

then on other .cpp files I only have to do

```
conn.execute("Query");
conn.fetch();
```

any idea how I could do this?

Comment: I dont think you can/should do that, you should open and close the database connection when needed. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: because I think that the server(program) should keep one connection instead of opening/closing connections every query

Comment: It's just matter of creating a connection object and passing about, but as @Victor says it's not the way you should do it. Pass the connection string about and use it in each db operation is the way to go. .Net pools connections by default, so doing this you fighting the way it's meant to work, which in general has some unfortunate consequences.

Comment: @user3742380. Have a look at .net connection pooling. It's doing what you want under the covers, so you don't have to bother with managing that side of the process

Comment: Something like this ? http://www.oschina.net/code/snippet_583625_19818

Comment: Unfamiliar with what that is, unless they've made a complete mammary gland out of the wrapper pooling should just happen at the application level.

Comment: hmm I dont really understand how the connection pooling would help with that what I want to do

Comment: try https://github.com/safeonlineworld/mysqlw